# Node.js require req.path?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, require

I have seen  below code from here..:https://levelup.gitconnected.com/the-definite-guide-to-handling-errors-gracefully-in-javascript-58424d9c60e6

```
router.use(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const route = require(`.${req.path}`)[req.method]
```

can someone tell me what require(req.path) is doing ? Normally I know require from importing modules, but not for requiring a request object from browser or so... 
What is require doing here?

Comment: It requires a file dynamically based on what the page's URL is. It's a terrible piece of code, basically a huge security vulnerability. Don't ever use it.

Comment: ah I think now I understand, it wants to import the file in the repo that has the same name as the request path url? :D and takes the methd (req.method) from the exported object right?